# How to get this google map design?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I using google map in my web application. But the problem is that my client wants exactly like in photo
[image]

What is the name of that design. I have to customize by myself or that is the design offered by Google API ?

Answer (score 1):

I normally use a service like this when I need to customise a Google map, http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html?utm_medium=twitter

There are other websites with similar tools, e.g. https://snazzymaps.com/ but I'd definitely recommend using one of these over coding it by hand.

Comment: @Waiyan no problems, feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it helped you out :)